# Adding progress bar spinner as a place holder for imageview in Android

Tags: android, spinner, progress, android-spinner, android-progressbar

I would like to put a spinner progress bar inside the imageview till the image loads from the internet. It is working fine with a static image.

There is a way to keep the progressbar inside a relative layout with the imageview. How can I implement that in my case?

Here is my Adapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {        
    view = new ImageView(parent.getContext());  
    view.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(260, 220));      
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(result.get(position).get("LogoUrl"), (ImageView) view);
    return view;
}
```

Method to set Image:

```
public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView)
{
    imageViews.put(imageView, url);
    Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);
    if(bitmap!=null)
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    else
    {
        queuePhoto(url, imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);                    
    }
}
```